# GET Response with several models

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have two ViewSets. They have unique serializer and model. For example, `CitiesViewSet` and `TypesViewSet`:

`CitiesViewSet` -

```
[{"name":"Moscow"},{"name": "Kazan"} etc...]
```

`TypesViewSet` -

```
[{"id": 1, "name": "sample"}, {"id": 2, "name": "sample"} etc... ]
```

I want to combine this ViewSets to one GET Response. For example, I can do GET request and I will get looks like -

```
 { "cities": 
  [
   {"name": "Moscow"},
   {"name": "Kazan"} etc...
  ], 
   "types": 
  [
   {"id": 1, "name": "sample"},
   {"id": 2, "name": "sample"} etc.
  ]
 }
```

How to create it?

**UPD**:

```
class CityViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    pagination_class = None
    queryset = City.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CitySerializer


class TypeViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    pagination_class = None
    queryset = Type.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TypeSerializer
```

So I want to create a new viewset contains two viewsets (check example)

Answer (score 0):

Viewsets offer a variety of methods like create, list, retrieve, update, ...

```
# import the serializers
# import JSONResponse 
# import the models

# in your viewset
def list(self, request):
    # print this to see what is it
    data_from_v1 = V1Serializer(queryset_of_model_1).data
    data_from_v2 = V2Serializer(queryset_of_model_2).data

    # return the dicts concatenated
    return JSONResponse(data_from_v1.append(data_from_v2))
    # calling super() will get a list of the model specified in META.model
    # you can do it and concatenate it with the other model too.
```

Comment: Hello! Can you provide more details about your code?
How I can paste it in ViewSet?

Comment: Are the 2 models related ? Is there any relations between them? Post them too please and I'll solve this